# Base type of ValueTuple<T1, T2>

Tags: c#-7.0, valuetuple

Can't figure out with next comparing:

```
var type = typeof(ValueTuple<int, string>);
if (type.BaseType == typeof(ValueTuple)) 
// returns 'false', however, 'type.BaseType' is 'System.ValueTuple' at runtime
```

Who can to explain that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As with any `struct` the base type is `System.ValueType`.

The similarity to the human eye got me confused for a minute or two.

Comment: I would like to delete my question because of _typo_, but I can't if any answers here

Comment: Don't be embarrassed by it. I only got to it because I knew it couldn't be anything other than `ValueType`.